# How to find the swift version used to build .ipa file

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, version

I don't have access to the source code but only the .ipa file and I'm to confirm as the QA to the project the swift version used to develop the .ipa file, how do I? I can get the iOS version using this command on the terminal.

```
plutil -p Payload/MyData.app/Info.plist | grep DTSDKName
```

Answer (score 3):

In Terminal, you can access the folder containing your .ipa file and unzip it.

```
unzip YourApp.ipa
```

You'll get then a folder called Payload containing your app (**XXXXXX.app**)

Then change the directory to be able to list what is in your app :

```
cd Payload/XXXXXX.app/
```

Once in your app folder structure, you should be able to see the **Info.plist** file.

If the plist file is in the binary format, you can convert it to XML first by running:

```
plutil -convert xml1 Info.plist
```

Then open the file :

```
vi Info.plist
```

In this file you should find **DTPlatformBuild** and **DTSDKBuild** which will contain a Build number.

This build number can be then found following the below url to get the information about the Xcode version used and the SDK versions to build the .ipa and also the release notes for each Xcode version.

https://xcodereleases.com

In the release notes, you should find a section for Swift details.